# Dual polyhedral cone

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The dual of a polyhedral cone is given by

$\sigma^\vee =\{m \in M_\mathbb{R} \mid \langle m,u\rangle =0 \ \forall \ u \in \sigma \}$

Where $M_\mathbb{R}$ the abelian group of all one parameter subgroups.

Then I wish to show that $\sigma^\vee $ is a polyhedral cone in $M_\mathbb{R}$ and that $(\sigma^\vee)^\vee=\sigma$. Where $M$ is the abelian group of all characters and I have defined a polyhedral cone to be of the form
$\sigma=Cone(S)=\{\sum_{u \in S} \lambda_u u \mid \lambda_u \geq 0 \}$.

The proof of this proposition is omitted in my book. Anyone who can give a link to a proof or show how to do it?

Comment: I think you should give in more detail the definitions of $M$ and $M_\mathbb{R}$

Comment: In the less abstract case, this question has an answer  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631289/dual-of-a-rational-convex-polyhedral-cone